# GDB - Address of breakpoint

Tags: assembly, gdb

I scripted a simply assembly code, and now i'm trying to debug it using gdb.

In gdb i typed :

```
(gdb) break _start
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4000b0
```

Is the breakpoint address (0x4000b0) relative to the hard-disk memory location of the code line ? Or is it only relative to the program length ?
(I think that at this point the program is still not loaded in RAM)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a virtual address in RAM.  You have a position-*dependent* executable, so the absolute address it *will* be loaded to is right there in the ELF metadata.  (you can use `readelf my_program`, or the GDB command `info files`.)

If you had a PIE executable and set a breakpoint before starting it, GDB will give you a breakpoint address that isn't relocated yet, so the first byte of the file is treated as address `0`.  e.g.

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x64e: file hello.c, line 3.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/hello

Breakpoint 1, main () at hello.c:3
(gdb) info br
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0x000055555555464e in main at hello.c:3
        breakpoint already hit 1 time
```

Note that `0x64e` and `0x000055555555464e` have the same offset within a 4k page, because the file gets mapped to a page-aligned address.

Comment: What the address 0x000055555555464e represents here ? It's a very big number o.o

Comment: @Koinos: PIE executables on x86-64 Linux are mapped outside of the low 32-bits of virtual address space by default, even with ASLR disabled.  Only position-*dependent* executables default to having their text segment at around `0x400000`.  `0x000055555555464e` is just a normal user-space virtual address (in the low half of virtual address space; the kernel reserves the high half for itself in every process).

Comment: Ah nice, i thought that the example you give using gdb shell referred to a ELF :)

Comment: @Koinos: PIE executables are ELF, but they're ELF shared objects with an entry point rather than the traditional "ELF Executable" file type.   See [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43367427) for more about them.