# Why do the addresses in my assembler dump differ from the addresses of registers?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, gdb

I have a very basic program that I compiled with

```
gcc -m32 -g -o hello32.out hello.c
```

When I run disassemble main in gdb I get the following output:

```
0x0000051d <+0>:    lea    ecx,[esp+0x4]
0x00000521 <+4>:    and    esp,0xfffffff0
0x00000524 <+7>:    push   DWORD PTR [ecx-0x4]
0x00000527 <+10>:   push   ebp
0x00000528 <+11>:   mov    ebp,esp
0x0000052a <+13>:   push   ebx
0x0000052b <+14>:   push   ecx
0x0000052c <+15>:   sub    esp,0x10
0x0000052f <+18>:   call   0x420 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx>
0x00000534 <+23>:   add    ebx,0x1aa4
0x0000053a <+29>:   mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],0x0
... [truncated for brevity]
```

However, when I run

```
(gdb) break main
(gdb) run
(gdb) info register eip
```

I get

```
eip            0x5655553a   0x5655553a <main+29>
```

Why is main+29 shown as 0x0000053a in the assembler dump but 0x5655553a when the address of eip is given?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your GCC makes PIE executables by default, so there is no fixed base address in the file (and disassembly shows it relative to 0, i.e. offsets rather than absolute addresses).**

Once the kernel's ELF program loader has created a running process from the executable (and chosen a virtual address as the base), GDB can show you the actual runtime virtual addresses.  (e.g. `starti` to start it running, *then* `disas my_func` to get a valid address within that process; GDB disables ASLR so it will be the same every time only if running under GDB, or with other ways of disabling ASLR for a specific run of a process or system-wide.)

**Build with `-fno-pie -no-pie`** to get position-*dependent* executables where the runtime address is known from the executable metadata.  (You should definitely prefer `-fno-pie` for i386 code: without RIP-relative addressing the extra performance / code-size cost of position-independent code is significantly worse than for x86-64.)

---

Related: [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43367427) for more about PIE (both 32-bit and 64-bit x86, and in general.)

[GDB - Address of breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53184915/gdb-address-of-breakpoint) is similar to this but not exactly a duplicate.